# Swift 3 conversion gets 'Int1' is not convertible to 'Bool'

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'm converting Swift 2 code that compiles and runs to Swift 3 and am getting the following error:

> 'Int1' is not convertible to 'Bool'

The code is as follows:

```
isUpdated = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(
"UPDATE Coin_Table SET upgrade=?, grade=?, WHERE coin_id=?", 
withArgumentsInArray: [
coinInfo.upgrade, (coinInfo.grade != nil) ? coinInfo.grade! : NSNull(), 
coinID])
```

The code above is using FMDB with the method defined in FMDB.h as

```
- (BOOL)executeUpdate:(NSString*)sql withArgumentsInArray:(NSArray *)arguments;
```

When compiling my code above it flags the "(coinInfo.grade !=" and gives the error.

I tried simplifying it to see if it would still happen:

```
let theArray: NSArray = [true ? "foo" : NSNull()]
```

and still get the same error, this time it flags the "true".

[image: Screenshot of error]

I've done a bunch of searches on this and haven't found anything close other than https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2372 but that is an issue with tuples which I wouldn't think would affect my code.

Can anyone shed some light on this or suggest a workaround if it is a compiler bug?

Thanks

Comment: `Builtint.Int1` is the internal representation of the `Bool` struct (`_value` property of the struct), and that this type pops up in an error/warning message generally points to non-intended behavior from the compiler. It does seem as if the bug report you link kind of explains this behaviour as well> the compiler can't infer the type of the result of the ternary operation. E.g. using the string literal to explicitly initialize an `NSString` instance (instead of trusting the compiler) will circumvent the error (`let theArray: NSArray = [true ? NSString(string: "foo") : NSNull()]`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I actually had simplified the actual code I was using for posting my question as I had multiple inserts on the same line so this method would have been a little unwieldy for me.  Went with the temp vars approach below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you wrote yourself your issue is the same as a one described [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2372). Bugs happens ))

Why not just to use a temporary variable to fix it:

```
let hasGrade: Any = (coinInfo.grade != nil) ? coinInfo.grade! : NSNull()
isUpdated = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(
"UPDATE Coin_Table SET upgrade=?, grade=?, WHERE coin_id=?", 
withArgumentsInArray: [
coinInfo.upgrade, hasGrade, 
coinID])
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me past the issue, hadn't used "Any" before.

Comment: Sometimes this error shows when you have a different error in your code.  I was confused about it, but I later figured out there was another error on that line that xcode wasn't reporting, and when I fixed that, this error went away.